# вывод связанных моделей в ListView

Tags: django

подскажите что я упустил. Только начал изучать django. Хочу выводить в родительской модели связанные поля из дочерней.
models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name_category = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'Название категории', max_length = 100, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="media/", verbose_name='Изображение')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_category


class Subcategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='категория', related_name='photos')
    name_subcategory = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'Название подкатегории', max_length = 100, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="media/", verbose_name='Изображение')
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=160, unique=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_subcategory
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView

from .models import Category,Subcategory

class CategoryView(ListView):
    """список категорий"""
    model = Category
```

в шаблоне(раньше использовал только функции и все выводилось примерно так)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %} 
{% for category in category_list %}
{{category.name_category}}
<img src="{{category.image.url}}" width="100px" height="100px">
   {% for sub in category.subcategory_set.all %}
      {{ sub }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Но под категории не выводятся

Comment: Не много не понял вопрос, уточни, что ты хочешь

Comment: @lleballex чтобы на странице с категориями выводились подкатегории

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не вижу у тебя нигде **subcategory_set**, как ты указал в шаблоне. Если посмотреть в моделях, то **related_name** ты указывал, как photos. Может попробовать так: `{% for sub in category.photos.all %}`

Comment: Неловкое чувство, что когда копировал случайно оставил related_name...думаю это поможет, приму ответ в скором времени как смогу подойти к пк

Comment: Должно помочь...